# Error 1064 on Mysql multiple action Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1064

I'm going crazy creating this trigger in MySql...
Could you find the error? :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `Gestione_qty_mov_magazzino` AFTER
INSERT ON `dj3u9lk_pods_flusso_merci_magazzi` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN  
DECLARE is_present INT default 0
SET is_present = SELECT COUNT(`dj3u9lk_pods_archivio_magazzino`.codice_articolo) FROM `dj3u9lk_pods_archivio_magazzino` WHERE `dj3u9lk_pods_archivio_magazzino`.codice_articolo = NEW.codice_articolo)
IF (is_present > 0) THEN
        UPDATE `dj3u9lk_pods_archivio_magazzino`
        SET `dj3u9lk_pods_archivio_magazzino`.quantita_presente = `dj3u9lk_pods_archivio_magazzino`.quantita_presente + NEW.quantita
        WHERE `dj3u9lk_pods_archivio_magazzino`.codice_articolo = NEW.codice_articolo AND NEW.tipo_movimentazione = 0
ELSE
        INSERT INTO `dj3u9lk_pods_archivio_magazzino` (codice_articolo) 
        VALUES NEW.codice_articolo      
END

 END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Every MySQL statement must have a terminator, usually ;

Comment: I know, but if I insert the terminator ; the interface sign an "unexpected character" in line, and if I try to submit SQL statement give me back same 1064 error... Other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have been a bit random with your backticks (I would remove them they aren't required) and and a bit sparing with bracketing - the select part of the set is_present needs to be bracketed as does the values clause in the insert statement. And yes the statements all need to be terminated with ;.
This code syntaxs for me.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Gestione_qty_mov_magazzino AFTER
INSERT ON dj3u9lk_pods_flusso_merci_magazzi FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN  
DECLARE is_present INT default 0;
SET is_present = (
        SELECT COUNT(dj3u9lk_pods_archivio_magazzino.codice_articolo) 
        FROM dj3u9lk_pods_archivio_magazzino 
        WHERE dj3u9lk_pods_archivio_magazzino.codice_articolo = NEW.codice_articolo
        ) ;
IF is_present > 0 THEN
        UPDATE dj3u9lk_pods_archivio_magazzino
        SET dj3u9lk_pods_archivio_magazzino.quantita_presente = dj3u9lk_pods_archivio_magazzino.quantita_presente + NEW.quantita
        WHERE dj3u9lk_pods_archivio_magazzino.codice_articolo = NEW.codice_articolo AND NEW.tipo_movimentazione = 0
    ;
ELSE
        INSERT INTO dj3u9lk_pods_archivio_magazzino (codice_articolo) 
        VALUES (NEW.codice_articolo)      ;
END if;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```